# WebView Progress ring windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, webview, progress-bar, windows-8.1

I have a problem, I want to use a Progress ring in webview but it does not do what I want it to do. The progress ring stays even if the page is loaded. I also want the buttons appear after loading.

Here's my code:

xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// Die Elementvorlage "Leere Seite" ist unter http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink  /?LinkId=234238 dokumentiert.

namespace Euregio_Systems
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Eine leere Seite, die eigenständig verwendet werden kann oder auf die     innerhalb eines Rahmens navigiert werden kann.
    /// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.euregio-systems.com", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "history.go(-1)" });
    }


    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.euregio-systems.com", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "histroy.go(+1)" });
    }
    private void webBrowser_NavigationCompleted(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        pr1.IsActive = false;
        pr1.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        webBrowser.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        fwd.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        backButton.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        homeButton.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
}
```

and xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView Name="webBrowser" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <AppBarButton Visibility="Collapsed" Name="backButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-20,-4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_1" Icon="Back"/>
    <AppBarButton Visibility="Collapsed" Name="homeButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,-4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_2" Icon="Home"/>
    <AppBarButton Visibility="Collapsed" Name="fwd" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,-4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Icon="Forward" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
    <ProgressRing Visibility="Visible" Name="pr1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsActive="True" Height="163" Width="170" Margin="0" RequestedTheme="Light"/>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Do you ever subscribe to the NavigationCompleted event in your code behind file?

Comment: How can I subscribe it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add this line before calling Navigate on the web browser in your code:

> `this.webBrowser.NavigationCompleted+= webBrowser_NavigationCompleted;`

Also you should ideally do this  on loaded event of WebView which can be added like this:

```
<WebView Name="webBrowser" Visibility="Collapsed" loaded="WebViewControl_Loaded"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have forgotten to subscribe to the event, you should open the Form/Page designer and check for the "Lightning" Icon to display the events you can subscribe to, like in this image

[image]

Just look for the `NavigationCompleted` event and put your callback method name (`webBrowser_NavigationCompleted`) in.

Though using the events is a bit discouraged these days. MVVM is the preferable method of developing Windows Store Apps (or any modern WPF Application) to fully utilize WPF's power of binding.

**Update:**
Or if you prefer it, you can also subscribe in code (just make sure you do it after the Components have been initialized):

```
this.webBrowser.NavigationCompleted += webBrowser_NavigationCompleted;
```

Comment: I don't have any "Lightning" icon :O

Comment: You have to switch to the **Designer**. The one where you design the layout of the page/dialog. Where your UI control properties are shown. It#s same window, where you can switch between properties and events

Comment: @Tseng OP is asking for Windows 8 app, your solution is for windows form app.

Comment: WPF supports events too, though it's discouraged to use them.